# ..Why req.session saved in sessionStore.sessions and How to access value from sessionStore

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, request, sessionid

i can see this after i code. but I wanted to use user Id. but if it is included in session store, i can't use it.. please help me.i thought it will be included in req.session. but it was not. it is in sessionStore.

```
            req.session.save(() => {
                req.session.userId = userInfo.id;
                res.json(userInfo);
            });
```

````
    sessions: [Object: null prototype] {
      CgqVPz78TUOK8McjkOTzOMlWscJZR4gi: '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":604800000,"expires":"2021-03-31T17:52:01.855Z","secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/","sameSite":"none"},"userId":1009}'
    },
    generate: [Function],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  sessionID: '-jwHBAmaNqHvHjDiGt533bITp3_M39bO',
  session: Session {
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      _expires: 2021-03-31T17:52:01.863Z,
      originalMaxAge: 604800000,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true
    }
  },```
````